# Can I increase number of topics quota per Azure EventGrid Domain?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud, azure-eventgrid

Currently, as per the pricing quota and limits available for **Azure Event Grid Domains** at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/quotas-limits

The following quotas and limits apply to Azure Event Grid domains.

| Resource | Limit |
| --- | --- |
| Topics per event domain | 100,000 |
| Event subscriptions per topic within a domain | 500 |
| Domain scope event subscriptions | 50 |
| Publish rate for an event domain (ingress) | 5,000 events/sec or 5 MB/sec (whichever is met first) |
| Event Domains per Azure Subscription | 100 |
| Private endpoint connections per domain | 64 |
| IP Firewall rules per domain | 16 |

**If the quota is exceeded say I want to create 1000 more topics after 100,000 limit is exhausted, is there a way to increase the quota limit in Microsoft Azure?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be increased for [some resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/quotas-limits) as per your scenario/usage. You can contact [support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) and they will further help you out if the limit can be increase or any alternative. If you are in the design phase of your solution, so please assume these limits and design for it.